# unable to access html element using cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I am trying to test the login functionalities using cypress, but for some reason I am unable to access the input text-box.
It shows Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: runner container, but never found it.

```
describe("User authentication", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit("https://lmflf.com");
     
    });
    it("it takes to the correct page", () => {
   
      cy.get('[data-field=password]')
      
    });
    
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see a shadow DOM in your webpage and in that case you have to use `.shadow()`([Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/shadow)). Your code would look something like:

```
cy.get('view-login').shadow().find('input[data-field="username"]').type('username', {force: true})
cy.get('view-login').shadow().find('input[data-field="password"]').type('password', {force: true})
cy.get('view-login').shadow().find('input[value="personal"]').click()
cy.get('view-login').shadow().find('.ViewLogin__button').click()
```

Comment: This is my first time hearing about this thing called shadow dom. Thanks it works now :)